# $\mu(X)<\infty$. $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure iff $\int_X \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}d\mu \rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f,f_n\in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mu(X)<\infty$. Then $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure if and only if $\int_X \frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}d\mu \rightarrow 0$.

To prove from left what I did is if the integral converges to 0 then either measure of $X$ is small or the term in it. First case gives the result directly. For second $|f_n-f|$ must converge to 0. Which means almost everywhere convergence and in finite measure space it implies convergence in measure by Egoroff's Theorem.

Is this true? And what should I do for $"\implies"$?

Comment: A standard fact from basic real analysis which should be helpful is that if $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\bar{d}(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is a bounded metric (i.e. takes values in $[0,1]$) with the same topology as $d$.

Comment: Thank you I thought of that too. But how can I get $d(f_n,f)<\epsilon$ from convergence in measure. Since it only implies $f_{n_k}\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint for $\Rightarrow$. You have that for all $\epsilon>0,\delta>0$ there exists an $N$ such that $\mu(|f_n-f|>\delta)<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Now split your integral into two pieces, one on which $|f_n-f|<\delta$ and one on which $|f_n-f|>\delta$. You can nicely bound your fraction on the $>\delta$ part using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Now also use the fact that the measure is finite.